# Why my arrays are returning object instead of numbers?

Tags: javascript

**I am trying to find Least Common Multiple. But when I tried to find the final result, I got *NaN* and realized both of my arrays are returning object. Sharing the code below -**

```
function myFunction(){
//For x
 var x = document.getElementById("int").value;
 let textx = "";
 let multiplex = [];
 //For y
 var y = document.getElementById("int1").value;
 let texty = "";
 let multipley = [];
 //result
 let result = "";
 //FINDING THE MUTIPLES OF X
  if(isNaN(x)==false){
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    if (i === 11) { break; }
    multiplex.push(((i*x)).toFixed(2));
    }
    textx += multiplex + " are the multiples of "+x;
}else{
  window.alert("Please input a number. "+x+" is not a number")
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textx;
//FINDING THE MULTIPLES OF Y
if(isNaN(y)==false){
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    if (i === 11) { break; }
    multipley.push(((i*y)).toFixed(2));
    }
    texty += multipley + " are the multiples of "+y;
}else{
  window.alert("Please input a number. "+y+" is not a number")
}
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = texty;
//Finding intersection and LCD
  const filtArray = multiplex.filter(value => multipley.includes(value));
  console.log(Math.min(filtArray))
//Testing typeof
  console.group(typeof multiplex) //result object
  console.group(typeof multipley) //result object
  
  //result += Math.min(filtArray) + "is the Least Common Multiple (LCM)"
  //document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: Objects as in `{}`? It looks more like strings instead of numbers. Convert this `var x = document.getElementById("int").value;` and `y` as well. when you get a value from any element it's going to be a string. `8` is a Number, `"8"` is a String, see the diff?

Comment: Tried using Number() but still multiplex and multipley is returning object instead of number.

Comment: `parseInt(x)` or `parseFloat(x)` or even coercion `(+x)`, but `Number(x)`  should work as well

Comment: parseFloat() has worked. Thanks.

Comment: When `.toFixed()` is applied to a number it changes it to a string, so `multiplex.push(((i*x)).toFixed(2));` makes an array of strings. Don't use `.toFixed()` until you are finished and want to display numbers with `.00`

Comment: Tried removing .toFixed() but it didn't work. Only parseFloat() seems to work here.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Math.min(...filtArray);" instead.
We use the spread operator ... when calling the Math.min method.

Since the Math.min method expects comma separated numbers as arguments, we can't directly pass it an array.

This works like a charm

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>JavaScript Numbers</h1>
    <h2>Least common multiple</h2>
    
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <p id="demo3"></p>
    
    <script>
    let num = 23;
    let n = num.toFixed();
    var x = 6;
     let textx = "";
     let multiplex = [];
     //For y
     var y = 3;
     let texty = "";
     let multipley = [];
     //result
     let result = "";
     //FINDING THE MUTIPLES OF X
      if(isNaN(x)==false){
      for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        if (i === 11) { break; }
        multiplex.push(((i*x)));
        }
        textx += multiplex + " are the multiples of "+x;
    }else{
      window.alert("Please input a number. "+x+" is not a number")
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textx;
    //FINDING THE MULTIPLES OF Y
    if(isNaN(y)==false){
      for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        if (i === 11) { break; }
        multipley.push(((i*y)));
        }
        texty += multipley + " are the multiples of "+y;
    }else{
      window.alert("Please input a number. "+y+" is not a number")
    }
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = texty;
    //Finding intersection and LCD
      const filtArray = multiplex.filter(value => multipley.includes(value));
      let textcommon = "Common multiples " + filtArray;
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = textcommon ;  //Math.min(filtArray);
      document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = Math.min(...filtArray);
      console.log(Math.min(filtArray))
    //Testing typeof
      console.group(typeof multiplex) //result object
      console.group(typeof multipley) //result object
      
      //result += Math.min(filtArray) + "is the Least Common Multiple (LCM)"
      //document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
    
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Least common multiple
6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60 are the multiples of 6

3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30 are the multiples of 3

Common multiples 6,12,18,24,30

6